# Where is `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` located in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

I have followed a couple tutorials that say to change `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in the `settings.py` file to customize redirect, but I cannot find it anywhere. I also read that it would be deprecated in Django 1.10 (which I am using) but it is still listed in the docs.. Where is `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` located or am i supposed to customize another way?

Comment: It's not there by default, you have to add it

Comment: Where did you read that it would be deprecated?

Comment: @JensAstrup that worked thanks! You can submit as answer so i can accept

Comment: I read it would be deprecated on another SO question

Comment: Seemed more like a comment solution, but added :)

Comment: The option to use an import path for a view function has been removed in 1.10, but the setting itself is still there and won't be deprecated anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` has a default value (`/accounts/profile/`) but it doesn't appear in `settings.py` by default, you need to add it in if you want to change it.

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/my_own_login_url'`

or, even better, as of 1.5 you can use your named URL patterns:

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'some_app:login'`

and I've checked the settings documentation for [1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url), [1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url), and [dev](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url), no deprecation warnings on any of them.